# Convert Primal LP to Dual and solve

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

I'm dealing with an LP of minimizing the maximum distance from a set of points $(1,1), (2,2), (2,4), (3,2)$ to at line $L:y=ax+b$

I've managed to formulate the LP as

\begin{aligned}
& \underset{\{a,b,d\}}{\text{minimize}}
& & d \\
& \text{ st.}
& & \begin{pmatrix}1&1&-1\\
-1&-1&-1\\2&1&-1\\-2&-1&-1\\2&1&-1\\-2&1&-1\\3&1&-1\\-3&1&-1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a\\b\\d \end{pmatrix}\leq\begin{pmatrix} 1\\-1\\2\\-2\\4\\-4\\2\\-2 \end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned}
How would one formulate this as a dual?

Comment: What do you already know about LP duality?  Are you familiar with the weak and strong duality theorems?  Do you know any primal-dual pairs of LPs?  Can your LP be put into the form of one of primal or dual LP's that you've already encounterd?

Comment: I'm familiar with weak and strong duality and I've managed to formulate as the program \begin{aligned}
& {\text{max}}
& & u_1-u_2+2u_3-2u_4+4u_5-4u_6+2u_7-2u_8 \\
& \text{ st.}
& & \begin{pmatrix}1&-1&2&-2&2&-2&3&-3\\
1&-1&1&-1&1&-1&1&-1\\
-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} u_1\\u_2\\u_3\\u_4\\u_5\\u_6\\u_7\\u_8 \end{pmatrix}
\leq\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned}

Comment: Assuming strong duality holds I should be able to solve this dual program like I would a primal by converting it to standard form and in this instance simply using the three added slack variables as a starting basis for the simplex algorithm. Would that correct?

Comment: It looks correct, but the $u$ variables should be negative (because in the primal, constraints are of $\le$ type).